# Selecting a random number within a series(python)

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create a program that picks a random number out of a series of 2 numbers, does anyone know how this is done? I looked it up and said to use the choice function, however an error came up saying I had given 3 arguments when the code needed only 2.

What do I have to do to make it pick a random number in a series?

```
variable = [choice(a,b),choice(a,b)]
variable = choice(1,5,9,27) #  variable should now = 1, 5, 9 or 27.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation states](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice), just write `choice((1, 5, 9, 27))`.

If you write `choice(1, 5, 9, 27)`, that is passing four arguments to the function.

If you write `choice((1, 5, 9, 27))`, that is passing a single argument, a tuple of four elements, `(1, 5, 9, 27)`, to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit misleading. `random.choice(seq)` takes a sequence. You can pass it an object like a list of values, or a tuple - anything that supports indexing.

If you want to pass it two values, a and b, you'll have to wrap them in something indexable. Try `choice([a,b])` or `choice((a,b))`. This first creates a list or tuple with two items and then passes that to the choice function.

A more explicit notation for the same thing is:

```
seq = (a,b)
variable = choice(seq)
```