# select a random variable within the list

Tags: python, random

I  have a set of questions here that I need to randomly select for the user and if the user loses a waiting time is required

```
decades = 100
ans = 0

ans = int (input ("halves of 40 =  "))
if ans == 20:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 10 =  "))
if ans == 5:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 90 =  "))
if ans == 45:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 20 =  "))
if ans == 10:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 80 =  "))
if ans == 40:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 30 =  "))
if ans == 15:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."

ans = int (input ("halves of 100 =  "))
if ans == 50:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."

ans = int (input ("halves of 60 =  "))
if ans == 30:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 50 =  "))
if ans == 25:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
ans = int (input ("halves of 70 =  "))
if ans == 35:
    print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
else:
    print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
```

Comment: That sounds great, do you have a question?

Comment: i need to randomly select one of the questions in order for the game to function as required to do so

Comment: @EdChum, read carefully, he have set of questions

Comment: @EdChum do you know how to write a code that would randomly select one of the questions within the code

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732330/selecting-a-random-number-within-a-seriespython?rq=1 and this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you might want to do something like that:

```
import random
tries = 10
questions = [("halves of 40 =  ",20),
             ("halves of 10 =  ",5),
             ("halves of 90 =  ",45),
             ("halves of 20 =  ",10),
             ("halves of 80 =  ",40),
             ("halves of 30 =  ",15),
             ("halves of 100 =  ",50)]

for i in xrange(tries):
    q = random.choice(questions)
    ans = int (input (q[0]))
    if ans == q[1]:
        print ans, " is a right ans good job!"
    else:
        print ans, "is a Wrong ans best of luck for next quation."
```